# Bouncycastle OpenSSL Padding Check Failed

Tags: openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

Basically doing what this example does, but just the signing part:

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/SendSignedAndEncryptedMail.java

Except I use JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder not JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder as I have to pass in the content signer with a hsm provider.

Once I have the signed message I can't seem to verify it using OpenSSL and get a:

Padding Check Failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make 100% certain that the publickey used to verify. most likely from the signer's cert you put in the message, matches the privatekey used to sign. Using mismatched RSA keys is most likely (about 90%?) to be first detected at the depadding step. If that's not it, do you have other cases this HSM works? Try to create a simpler example that just signs and verifies some small fixed data, without all the complications of SMIME.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, we use this library for a tonne of signing and decryption/encryption purposes across PGP and x509 with a number of business partners. Ok. Will double check the keys.